# Possible number of permutations with constraints

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

We have $5$ objects: A,B,C,D,E.

The number of permutation possible is $5!$.

But I have some constraints:

- The first and the last position can only be occupied by A, B or C
- There can be a repetition at the end of A, B, C 
  (for example A, B, C, D, E, A)

To resume: If A,B,C are entry or exit points (considering it's a chain), how many possible chains are possible?

EDIT:
Thanks lulu, rules indeed are those:
*To be clear, the rules I am guessing are: either you have a string of length 5 or length 6. The first type are just permutations of your five letters. The second type has a redundant A,B,C at the end. In both cases we require that the first and last character be one of A,B,C*

Comment: The question is not clear.  If repetition is permitted, the length of the chain is indeterminate.

Comment: This is not clear at all.  If I had to guess, I'd say:  first do the non-repeat case.  Then choose the first ($3$ options), choose the last ($2$ options), permute the other three ($3!$ options) so $3\times 2\times 3!$.  then do the repeat case.  Pick the first, ($3$ options), pick the last ($3$ options), and permute the other four ($4!$ options), so $3\times 3\times 4!$.  But I'm not sure I have the right rules.

Comment: To be clear, the rules I am guessing are:  either you have a string of length $5$ or length $6$.  The first type are just permutations of your five letters.  The second type has a redundant $A,B,C$ at the end.  In both cases we require that the first and last character be one of $A,B,C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases. If the string is of length $5$, so a permutation of ABCDE starting and ending with A, B or C, there are $3$ possibilities for the first letter. For each of these there are $2$ possibilities for the *last* letter. Now for each permutation of first and last letter there are $3!$ ways to arrange the middle three letters, giving $3\times2\times 3!$.

For the strings of length $6$ there are $3$ choices for the first letter and $3$ for the last letter (since these may be the same). Now the remaining letters are the four missing letters if the first and last are the same; otherwise they are the three missing letters plus another copy of the last letter. In either case there are four different letters to arrange in the middle, so $4!$ possibilities.

Overall, there are $3\times2\times 3!+3\times3\times4!$ suitable strings.